# Count only 1 if there's a row data exist?

Tags: mysql

I have this capstone project that need to finish tomorrow. They suggest that I should count the number of student violators by gender/course/violation.
the only problem is, is there a query that if a 2 or more violation offense has been committed by the student, the result will only show that counts as 1 student violator.

This is the image sample of my student violation table.

[image]

Sorry for my bad grammar.

Comment: What code you have already written?

Comment: Sideote, having a string in `NumberOfViolation` is poor database design

Comment: You can GROUP BY student id

Comment: @Supriya I have only this query to check the number violations commited depending on the selected date.
   query = "select Datecommit,count(NameOfViolation) AS RESULTCOUNT FROM cdm.tablestudentviolations where Datecommit BETWEEN '" & startFromDate & "' AND '" & startToDate & "' and NameOfViolation= '" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

Comment: @baao got that noted. Thank you!

Comment: You need to learn about `JOIN` so you can get student personal data (gender, course) along with violations.  You need to learn about `COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY` so you can get the aggregate--summary--data you need. You can read about those things.

Comment: @CBroe I've only got few days to add the suggestion of our panelist into my system. So many suggestions though. As a student, I am still learning more about programming. But thanks btw! :)

Comment: @O.Jones Yup, Got that. On going coding for the JOIN query! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use SELECT DISTINCT for such cases.
For example:

`SELECT DISTINCT StudentNumber FROM my_table WHERE TypeOfViolation="SomeType";`

You can refere here for more details:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: This answers my question! Thank you! :)